# sql server 2008 query with if clause or case?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

here is my data:

```
liza
liza
liza
alex
alex
alex
liza
```

i would like to update this table with data for every occurrence of every name like this:

```
liza    4
liza    4
liza    4
alex    3
alex    3
alex    3
liza    4
```

so far i have:

```
update table set column2=count(name) group by name
```

thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update T1 set
  Column2 = T2.C
from YourTable as T1
  inner join (
                select count(*) as C, Name
                from YourTable
                group by Name
             ) as T2  
    on T1.Name = T2.Name
```

Sample with a table variable

```
declare @YourTable table 
(
  Name varchar(10),
  Column2 int
)

insert into @YourTable (Name) values
('liza'),('liza'),('liza'),('alex'),('alex'),('alex'),('liza')

update T1 set
  Column2 = T2.C
from @YourTable as T1
  inner join (
                select count(*) as C, Name
                from @YourTable
                group by Name
             ) as T2  
    on T1.Name = T2.Name
```

Try it here. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/102392/update-with-count

Here is another way using a CTE and `count(*) over()`.

```
declare @YourTable table 
(
  Name varchar(10),
  Column2 int
)

insert into @YourTable (Name) values
('liza'),('liza'),('liza'),('alex'),('alex'),('alex'),('liza')

;with cte as
(
  select Column2,
         count(*) over(partition by Name) as C
  from @YourTable        
)
update cte set
  Column2 = C
```

And this query you can try here. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/102394/update-with-count-2

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Ambiguous column name 'name'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Ambiguous column name 'name'.

Comment: @I__ – Updated answer with some code using table variables that you could test. I guess you have a typo in your version.